# Change state of link in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax function that has two outcomes depending on the class of the link clicked.

I don't want to reload the whole page when the link is clicked, so I have used:

This all works except as far as jQuery is concerned, it appears as if it still has the original class, so clicking on it again, just refires the "shortlist-add" script instead of the "shortlist-remove" script.

`<button data-propref="261" id="prop-261" class="btn-round btn-favorite shortlist-remove"><span class="icon-hearth"></span></button>`

```
// remove property from shortlist
jQuery('.shortlist-remove').on('click',function() {

    var propref = jQuery(this).data('propref');

    jQuery.ajax({
        url : ajax_object.ajax_url,
        type : 'post',
        data : {
            action : 'shortlist_rem',
            propref : propref
        },
        success : function( response ) {
            jQuery('.personal-nav').load(document.URL +  ' .personal-nav');
            jQuery('#prop-' + propref).removeClass('shortlist-remove').addClass('shortlist-add');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Not clear what the question is - can you rephrase? Are you trying to remove an event bound to `.click()` as well as modify the class?

Comment: Please could you also create a [MCVE]

Comment: G0dsquad, yes I think that's what I'm trying to do!

Comment: If you could follow @Pete above and provide the minimum JS, CSS and HTML it should be easier to assist you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a class that stays all the time as your main selector.

Then use conditionals based on the other 2 classes to change behaviors...in this case switching the `action`.

Then toggle the classes in the success handler

```
$('.btn-favorite').on('click', function(e) {
  var $btn = $(this),
    isRemove = $btn.hasClass('shortlist-remove'),
    propref = jQuery(this).data('propref');

  jQuery.ajax({
    ....
    data: {
      // action determined by classes
      action: isRemove ? 'shortlist_rem' : 'shortlist_add',
      propref: propref
    },
    success: function(response) {

      // toggle the classes now that ajax successful
      $btn.toggleClass('shortlist-remove shortlist-add');

      // other stuff
    }
  });

})
```